# Visual studio express 2013 for web having trouble to connect with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

So, basically it shows this error whenever i clicked "OK" button and i have googled about this but still can't find the problem.

[image]

Below is the data source.

Data Source=". \SQLEXPRESS";Initial Catalog=Books;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Are you sure you have Sql express running on local machine? The error says that it can not find the server so it can not connect to it.

Comment: oh i see then, thanks for that!